# how to create a branch locally from another local branch in git extensions

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-extensions

I'm new to using Git, currently I'm using Git Extensions V2.48, I'm trying to create a local branch where I can make changes without effecting my current network branch. Currently I have checkout a remote branch ABC123 and I want to create an another new local branch with this ABC123 so I can work on new branch with my ideas and come back to ABC123 without losing data so I can push my changes in ABC123 to Remote (or work simultaneously in both local branches without disturbing another code).

I have gone through online resource, where I can find how to create a new branch
http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/branches.html,
I have not tried it practically as I'm not sure what it does and I dont want to mess up with my branches on server/Remote.

please can any one help me how to do this in Git Extensions. Thanks.

[image: Git_Ext_V2.48]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the commit from where you want to create a new branch, select "Create new Branch" and that's it.

Just do not push your branch back to the remote and you're fine.

Btw.: You shouldn't check out a remote branch directly. Normally you would create a local branch with the same name and "link" it with the remote branch. GitExtensions does this automatically.

Comment: Hi @matthias, thanks for the reply. I have updated my post with the image showing what you said. I just wanted to make clear after clicking 'Create Branch' in the image creates a local branch and checkout any remote branch into it and just do not push it back to work locally.